# D3 - Creating multiple circles elements for every entry in dataset

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following dataset:

```
    "data":[
            ["1951","306","27","159","34","82","4"],
            ["1956","426","41","203","47","119","16"],
            ["1959","562","67","267","48","148","32"],
            ["1960","605","76","282","54","157","36"],
            ["1961","665","88","310","57","168","42"],
            ["1962","749","116","340","60","189","44"],
            ["1963","847","140","375","63","215","54"],
            ...
```

The first entry in each array is the year. I have created 2 coordinate axes w.r.t. this data. Now for each of these entries I want to create 6 circle elements. How can I do this using a variation of the following line:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data.data)
                .enter()
                .append("circle");

var circleAttr = circles. //Attributes defined here
```

Comment: in this data `"1951","306","27","159","34","82","4"` what is `,"306","27","159","34","82","4"` how will you create the circle's center and what about the radius

Comment: @Cyril `1951` is the year. All the others will be plotted with respect to 1951 on the xAxis. All these show different data related to 1951. They will be plotted straight away according to my y axis.

Comment: I think you need a scatter chart. http://bl.ocks.org/weiglemc/6185069

Comment: @Cyril Yes. But I need to plot 6 circles for each group. How do I do that? You see what I'm doing right now creates 1 circle corresponding to each year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.selectAll(...).data(...).enter(...).append(...)` pattern twice in a row, passing a function to `.data` the second (and later) time, where you accept the data from the previous level and return an array of data items for that level.

Here's a little example using your data:

```
var colors = d3.scale.category10().domain([1951, 1963]);

var data = [
  ["1951", "306", "27", "159", "34", "82", "4"],
  ["1956", "426", "41", "203", "47", "119", "16"],
  ["1959", "562", "67", "267", "48", "148", "32"],
  ["1960", "605", "76", "282", "54", "157", "36"],
  ["1961", "665", "88", "310", "57", "168", "42"],
  ["1962", "749", "116", "340", "60", "189", "44"],
  ["1963", "847", "140", "375", "63", "215", "54"]
];

d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1000)
  .attr("height", 1000)
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(function(d) {
    var year = +d[0];
    return d.slice(1).map(function(value) {
      return {
        year: year,
        value: +value
      };
    });
  })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 2)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return colors(d.year);
  });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/vvera4w9/